# SQL statement, subquery count?

Tags: sql, hql, criteria

I've got the following SQL tables

**Department**

```
|name|employees|
```

**Employee**

```
|name|gender|type|dead |
|John|male  |good|yes  |
|Mary|female|bad |no   |
|Joe |male  |ugly|maybe|
```

I would like to write a statement that returns

```
| type | n of employees | n of male employees | n of departments |
```

I've got

```
SELECT e.type, count(e), count(d) 
FROM Department d 
JOIN d.employees e
WHERE e.dead = maybe 
GROUP BY e.type
```

That's missing the 'n of male employees', of course. I'm stuck here, since I'm not sure, where to specify the additional clause e.gender = male.

I forgot to mention: HQL or criteria would be nice.

Comment: LOL! "dead = maybe", sorry for offtopic

Comment: The schema, as it appears in your question right now, does not contain any sort of link between `Employee` and `Department`. In other words, there doesn't appear to be any way to determine which employees work in a particular department or what department an employee works in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'dead' is a 2-state boolean.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm more concerned about the possibility of transitioning from one state to another than I am about the number of states.

Comment: The database is actually much more complex, it's just a simplifying example. And of course, there a links between those tables. I just left them out since it's probably pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference:

```
SELECT 
   e.type, 
   count(e), 
   count(d), 
   sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end)
from Department d 
JOIN d.employees e
WHERE e.dead = 'maybe' 
GROUP BY e.type
```

works in HQL. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your original query and schema is correct:

```
SELECT 
   e.type, 
   count(e), 
   count(d), 
   count (case when gender = 'male' then 1 else NULL end) AS NumberOfMaleEmployees
from Department d 
JOIN d.employees e
WHERE e.dead = 'maybe' 
GROUP BY e.type
```

Comment: shouldn't that be sum(case...)?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat yep, but count 0 still counts the 0 does it not?

Comment: @Mitch - If you use `COUNT` then  your `CASE` is irrelevant.  It will always increment regardless of whether the employee is male or not.

Comment: @JNK: Fixed. replaced with NULL (I should know better than answer questions when its late)... :(

Comment: Works great in plain SQL. Does anyone know how I can do that in HQL/JPQL (seems case statements are not supported) or Criteria? Sorry, should have mentioned it in the first place...