# HQL count statement

Tags: hql, aggregate-functions

I having a code like this

```
 (case app.test when 2 then ''  end) as tested
```

I am trying to get count of this app.state so written like this after referring to this document http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-aggregation

```
 count (case app.test when 2 then 'tested'  end) as tested
```

After this I getting error like

```
unexpected token: case
```

Any idea

But the same statement is working mysql

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN app.test= 2 THEN "tested" END) 'tested',
```

Comment: i dont think hql allows u to use aggregate function count with case.. u might have to use sql query. look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068051/case-statement-in-hql-or-criteria?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: No hql allows aggregate functions .I have used them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by

```
sum(case when app.test=2 then 1 else 0 end) as tested
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(app.state) as Confirmed from App app where app.state=2
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but here I have to apply count for case statements that is the problem