# Case Statement in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am very new in `hibernate` I have an `MySQL Query` and I want to achive same output using `Hibernate criteria`

**MySQL Query:**

```
SELECT *, 
(case when status = 'Active' 
    then 'Can Login' 
    else 'Not able to login' end) as LoginStatus  
FROM UserLoginTable;
```

My Hibernate Code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
Session session_hiber = sessionFactory.openSession();

session_hiber.beginTransaction();
Criteria criteria;

    criteria = session_hiber.createCriteria(UserLoginTable.class);
    List<UserLoginTable> myUserList = (List<UserLoginTable>)   
    criteria.list();
```

How I can add the `Case criteria` in the above code.
Is there any way ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although I did not test this snippet, you may try to use CriteriaBuilder something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = session_hiber.getCriteriaBuilder();
cb.selectCase()
    .when(cb.equal(path.get("status"), "Active"), "Can Login")
    .otherwise("Not able to login")
    .alias("LoginStatus");
```

Some help/info can be found here:

- [CASE statement in HQL or Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068051/case-statement-in-hql-or-criteria)
- [Using the 'case...when...then...else...end' construct in the 'having' clause in JPA criteria query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088736/using-the-case-when-then-else-end-construct-in-the-having-clause-in)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html